# Maximum number of requests for free tariff on openshift

Tags: openshift

I use the free tariff for the openshift of backend my application. 
In the example given on page https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing load of the following characteristics: 
15 pages / second
Hundreds of articles
~ 50k visitors per month
but does that mean that the application will be disabled until next month, if the number of requests to it are exceeding the allowable number? and if so, what is the number?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of a third party service.

Comment: @Juhana, they closed their forum and redirected to http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

That does not mean the application will be disabled.  That is just letting you know about the amount of traffic that a small gear can handle.